# Search many expressions in many documents using Python

Tags: python, nlp

I often have to search many words (1000+) in many documents (million+). I need position of matched word (if matched).

So slow pseudo version of code is

```
for text in documents:
     for word in words:
             position = search(word, text)
             if position:
                  print word, position
```

Is there any fast Python module for doing this? Or should I implement something myself?

Comment: Millions of documents for 1000s of words? Why do you think your solution would be better than the dozens of solutions out there? Millions of documents is not trivial.

Comment: @Falmarri: I think the point of the question is to find one of those dozens of solutions in Python module form.

Comment: So basically you're just wanting a full-text index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fast exact-text, multi-keyword search, try acora - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/acora/1.4

If you want a few extras - result relevancy, near-matches, word-rooting etc, Whoosh might be better - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/1.4.1

I don't know how well either scales to millions of docs, but it wouldn't take long to find out!

Comment: EXisting full-text index search systems are definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for tips, exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)?

So you have to use python? How about:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('grep <pattern> <file>')
```

which is insane. But hey! You are using python ;-)

Comment: Grep is fine, but I have to use Python. And I think this shouldn't be problem for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `documents` is a list of strings, you can use `text.index(word)` to find the first occurrence and `text.count(word)` to find the total number of occurrences.  Your pseudocode seems to assume words will only occur once, so `text.count(word)` may be unnecessary.